AG-Charts combination bar and line - line chart behind bars
using "react": "^18.3.1","ag-charts-react": "^10.2.0", and the javascript version of ag-charts.
I created a combination char of stacked bars and a line chart with ag chart.
But the line chart appears behind the bars.
As defined the rendering order is the same as in the series defined. But it seems there is an issue.
created a bar const for each bar.
const BAR# = {
    xKey: "category",
    stacked: true,
    fillOpacity: 0.7,
    yKey: "x",
    yName: "x",
};

const LINE = {
    xKey: "category",
    yKey: "x",
    yName: "x",
    stroke: "#00FF00",
    strokeWidth: 2, 
    marker: {
        enabled: true,
        fill: "#00FF00",
        stroke: "#00FF00", 
        size: 8, 
    },
};

const BAR_AND_LINE = [
    { ...BAR1, type: "bar" },
    { ...BAR2, type: "bar" },
    { ...BAR3, type: "bar" },
    { ...BAR4, type: "bar" },
    { ...BAR5, type: "bar" },
    { ...BAR6, type: "bar" },
    { ...BAR7, type: "bar" },
    { ...LINE, type: "line" },
];



Can you provide more code from your example so that I can replicate this? Or even better a codesandbox or plnker live repro.
